Text direction is changed to right-to-left in Intellij Idea 2023.2.5
Text direction in Intellij is changed from left-to-right to right-to-left.
I tried to change the direction as suggested on Internet.
i.e Goto BiDi Text Direction - select left-to-right option. 
But this option didn't work for me.

In the above photo, I am trying to write System but the cursor remains at the beginning of the line and the words are printed in reverse order.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Most right-to-left languages don't use Roman alphabets. So if you are able to write in another notepad correctly, it should eliminate any connection with locale and keyboard configurations in os.
